# Add open/close text to an expanding ad based on it's state

Tags: javascript, toggle, ads

I've got javascript displaying an expanding ad by first showing it as a 960x30, wait 3 seconds, expand it to 960x300, wait 3 seconds, then contract it back to 960x30.  Once this process has completed, the user can click it to toggle between the two sizes.  We serve the ad via Google Ad Manager so I detect to see if there is an ad to show and if there is I am putting the slider class on the div that Google automatically wraps the ad in.

What I need is to have either text or a graphic that toggles between "Expand" (when it's in the 960x30 state) and "Collapse" (when it's in the 960x300 state) in the corner of the ad while still allowing the rest of the ad to be clicked as a normal ad.  I hope that all makes sense and I am really hoping someone can take this home for me!!!  Here's the code I have:

```
<head>

<!-- load jquery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery1_7.js"></script>
<!-- load jquery : end -->

<!-- load google DFP -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://partner.googleadservices.com/gampad/google_service.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    GS_googleAddAdSenseService("ca-pub-XXX");
    GS_googleEnableAllServices();
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    GA_googleAddSlot("ca-pub-XXX", "TEST_960x300");
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    GA_googleFetchAds();
</script>
<!-- load google DFP : end -->

<!-- intial load as open and click toggle -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
$('.slider').delay(3000).animate({height:300}).delay(3000).animate({height:30}, function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        if ($(this).height()==30) {
            $(this).animate({height:300});
        } else {
            $(this).animate({height:30});
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
<!-- intial load as open and click toggle : end -->


<!-- slider class -->
<style type='text/css'>
.slider {
    width:960px;
    height:30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 0px;
    position: relative;
}
</style>
<!-- slider class : end -->

</head>

<body>

<p>stuff above the slider</p>

<!-- TEST_960x300 -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
GA_googleFillSlot("TEST_960x300");
</script>
<!-- TEST_960x300 : end -->

<p>stuff below the slider</p>



<!-- detect if DFP has an ad in the ad slot -->
<script type='text/javascript'>

if(document.getElementById('google_ads_div_TEST_960x300_ad_container')){
    document.getElementById('google_ads_div_TEST_960x300_ad_container').setAttribute("class", "slider");
}

//For IE since it seems DFP outputs a different div for IE.
if(document.getElementById('google_ads_div_TEST_960x300')){
    document.getElementById('google_ads_div_TEST_960x300').setAttribute("class", "slider");
}

</script>
<!-- detect if DFP has an ad in the ad slot : end -->


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to reorganize your JS a little bit, to make this task easier:

```
function openAd() {
    // stop any current animation
    // slide the ad open
}
function closeAd() {
    // stop any current animation
    // slide the ad closed
}
```

If I understand your question correctly, the rest is pretty straightforward:

- **Create the "Expand" and "Collapse" buttons, and add them to the DOM.** These could just be normal `<a>` elements, or buttons, or whatever. Not a big deal.
- **Control when each button is showing, based on the current state of the ad.** When the ad is collapsed, only show the expand button. When the ad is expanded, only show the collapsed button.
- **Add event listeners to the buttons.** Because you're using jQuery, this should be no problem. Something like `$(yourExpandButton).on('click', openAd);` (Note that that uses the 1.7 `on` function.)

Comment: There is a slightly different way to do it, if this isn't DRY enough for you. You could just create one button, and switch it's text (or image, or whatever) between "Expand" and "Collapse," and you could just have one "open/close" function that expands or collapses the ad based on its current state. It's mostly a matter of taste.

Comment: I would rather do it this way but I'm not a javascripter and not even sure where to start. A little lost...